# How to reduce cyclomatic complexity in for...if loop in c#

Tags: c#, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a simple code to print the rows and columns of a CSV file. This is my code and the cyclomatic complexity is coming out to be 6 for this class. I want to reduce it to as low as possible.

```
class PrintCSV
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Print all the rows of CSV File 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lines"> </param>

    public static void PrintCSVRows(string[] lines)
    {

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Contains(','))
            {
                string columns = line.Split(',')[1];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns))
                {
                    PrintCSVCol(columns);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the column of CSV File
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columns"></param>

    public static void PrintCSVCol(string columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", columns);
    }

}
```

How do I change the loops to reduce the overall cyclomatic complexity??

Comment: Refactor recipe: Extract method

Comment: This function is doing a lot - it is processing each line in an array, it is filtering away certain lines (== choosing certain lines to further process), it is processing a single line.  Why not split those things into separate functions and see what happens?  It's better software engineering - easier to test, for example.

Comment: I don't know about complexity, this seems relatively simple code to me. Although you could perhaps separate it into more functions (and then someone will debate whether that increases complexity in a different way no doubt!). But anyway IMHO `&& line.Contains(',')` is a bug because if the line contains just one column of data, applying this condition will mean that it won't print anything. And also `line.Split(',')[1]` ensures that it will only ever print the 2nd column of data. So this code doesn't "print the rows and columns of a CSV file", it's much more restricted than that.

Comment: @rene I've addressed that, see updated comment. The code doesn't do what the initial description claims it will do. Hard to know if that's intentional though - maybe it's just badly described.

Comment: Questions asking for help improving working code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. They _may_ be on-topic at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but you need to read their tour and make sure you meet their requirements (the above probably does not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to reduce cyclomatic complexity only, you can extract methods like the following:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Print all the rows of CSV File 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="lines"> </param>
public static void PrintCSVRows(string[] lines)
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        PrintLine(line);
    }
}

private static void PrintLine(string line)
{
    if (IsValidLine(line))
    {
        string columns = line.Split(',')[1];
        PrintCSVCol(columns);
    }
}

private static bool IsValidLine(string line)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Contains(',');
}

/// <summary>
/// Prints the column of CSV File
/// </summary>
/// <param name="columns"></param>
public static void PrintCSVCol(string columns)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", columns);
    }
}
```

With this code, each method has a cyclomatic complexity of 2 according to Visual Studio.
[image: cyclomatic complexity]

**However**, cyclomatic complexity is just a metric and doesn't necessarily mean that this code is *better*.

Answer (score 1):

This code does the same thing:

```
public static void PrintCSVRows(string[] lines)
{
    foreach (var columns in lines
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .Where(x => x.Length > 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x[1]))
        .ToArray())
    {
        PrintCSVCol(columns[1]);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public static void PrintCSVRows(string[] lines)
{
    foreach (var columns in lines
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
        .Select(x => x.Skip(1).First())
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
    {
        PrintCSVCol(columns);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could drop the `if(columns.Count > 1)` by switching to `PrintCSVCol(columns.FirstOrDefault())` with the null check in the `PrintCSVCol` function.

Comment: @asawyer that wouldn't do  the same thing, it would print null

Comment: You can get the `foreach` down to this: `foreach (var columns in lines.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1).Take(1)))`.

Comment: @Enigmativity that would perform differently in some corner cases (like "" or  ",sth,sth"), but the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries is a good suggestion.